# ReactiveSwift SignalProducer : Argument 'failed' must precede argument 'value'

Tags: swift, reactive-swift

I am trying to update an upgrade an old piece of code using ReactSwift because I want ti run it with XCode 9. I have defined a class Network

```
final class Network: NSObject {
    static func request(_ URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> SignalProducer<Any, NetworkError> {
        return SignalProducer { sink, disposable in
            Alamofire.request(URLRequest)
                .validate()
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        sink.send(value: value)
                        sink.sendCompleted()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        // modification en as NSError
                        sink.send(error: NetworkError(error: error as NSError))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

that is called in function using generic type:

```
private func fetch<T: Himotoki.Decodable>(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> SignalProducer<T, NetworkError> {
return Network.request(URLRequest)
    .attemptMap { JSON in
        do {
            return .success(try decodeValue(JSON) as T)
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.incorrectDataReturned)
        }
}
```

}

The generic function is used to make network requests using Alamofire, like the following one.

```
// Get static UserData
static func fetchUserData() -> SignalProducer<UserData, NetworkError> {
    return fetch(URLRequest: MoneyCupUsersBackEndRouter.getUserData)
}
```

So, I call :

```
    API.fetchUserData()
        .on(started: {
            SVProgressHUD.show()
        },
            value: { cfg in
                globalConfig = cfg
            },
            failed: { [weak self] error in
                self?.view.window?.dodo.error("Impossible de récupérer la configuration globale")
            },
            terminated: {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        })
        .start()

}
```

This scheme has worked well before and I have a large number of it across my code. But since I have upgraded to ReactiveCocoa, my code no longer compile. And I have a message stating that :

Argument 'failed' must precede argument 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be that for Swift functions where the arguments have default values you could reorder the arguments as desired at the call site. [This feature was removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0060-defaulted-parameter-order.md), which means you now must specify arguments in the same order as they are defined. So for the call to the `on` [function](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L1941), you must move the `value:` parameter to the end.